# How to nest different modules in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

```
The app.module has the admin-layout.module.
The admin-layout.module has the parameters.module.
The parameters.module has the soa-date.Component.
But the property.component is in the admin-layout.module
```

I need to put the `<app-soa-date></app-soa-date>` selector in the property.component but it gives me an error of app-soa-date is not a known element.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div *ngIf="showSoaDate">
    <app-soa-date></app-soa-date>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="showOther">
    Other
  </div>
</div>
```

Please see the image below:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the component too in your ParamatersModule

```
declarations: [
....
],
exports: [
  SoaDateComponent 
]
```

Comment: There's a typo in this answer. Please change `declearations` to `declarations`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export `SoaDateComponent` component from your `ParametersModule`.

```
exports: [
  SoaDateComponent
]
```